# Branch points and branch cuts(or surface) in two variables

Tags: complex-analysis

For the one complex variable case, the concept of branch points and branch cuts is well understood. What about two variables or more? Is there a systematic study of these for complex variables in 'n-variables'? As a simple example what would the sheet( or the generalization of it ) structure of function $\log[z_1-z_2]$ or power function of the form $(1-z_1-z_2)^{1/2}$ would be like?

Comment: From one-variable complex analysis, you should know that branch cuts are the wrong way to view things.  Branch/Ramification points, on the other hand, generalises to branch/ramification locus.

Comment: So can you direct me to some references on this subject?